# Can't get image width and height property from base64 data

Tags: html, image, events, onload, filereader

I am uploading an image and i expect base64 data of that image.I am trying below code that works to get image data as base64.

```
1) function getImage(file,count) //file is files[i] of input:file passed from for()
{
if(file)
{            
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event)
    {
        var data = event.target.result;
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.id = 'img'+count;
        image.class = 'edit';
        image.src = data;             
        console.log('width:'+this.width);//not working value is undefined
        console.log('height:'+this.height);//not working value is undefined
        //image.title = 'click to edit';
        image.data = count;
        data = image.dataset;
        data.ref=count;
        document.getElementById('image'+count).appendChild(image); 
        jQuery(document.getElementById('image'+count)).removeClass('disable');
        jQuery(document.getElementById('img'+count)).addClass('action editable img ');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
```

This works fine and it creates an img tag with image loaded correctly.

But I want to know the image width and height before creating `img` element, so i tried below code,

```
2) function getImage(file,count)
{
if(file)
{            
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event)
    {
        var img = new Image(); 
        var data = event.target.result;
        img.onload = function(){
            console.log(img.width);
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.id = 'img'+count;
            image.class = 'edit'; 
            image.src = data;         
            console.log('width:'+this.width);
            console.log('height:'+this.height);
            image.data = count;
            data = image.dataset;
            data.ref=count;
            document.getElementById('image'+count).appendChild(image); 
            jQuery(document.getElementById('image'+count)).removeClass('disable');
            jQuery(document.getElementById('img'+count)).addClass('action editable img ');
        };
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
```

But the second code does not prints log and img tag is not created. so what is the problem?What wrong in my code?Any better way to achieve this?.

Comment: have you tried? "img.width" instead of "this.widht" ?

Comment: yes @WaqasAhmed , even simple `console.log('myname');` is not working at first line of onload function.

Comment: I'm trying FileReader example on following URL: http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/KjEHg

and just edit var imageData = reader.result;
          
          
          var i = new Image(); 

          i.onload = function(){
           alert( i.width+", "+i.height );
          };

          i.src = imageData;

in reader.onload function, please try.

Comment: or might be your browser doesn't support FileReader API. Hence therefore might be your reader.onload not call on your browser. try to run your code on FileReader Supported Browser

Comment: No, I am using firefox 31.0.

Answer (score 0):

just single line makes my problem null,
Thanks to [this](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100115926/imgonload-function-doesnt-seem-to-be-ever-called).

```
function getImage(file,count)
{
if(file)
{            
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event)
    {
        var img = new Image(); 
        var data = event.target.result;
        img.src = data; //this line solved my problem..
        img.onload = function(){
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.id = 'img'+count;
            image.class = 'edit'; 
            image.src = data;         
            console.log('width:'+this.width);
            console.log('height:'+this.height);
            image.data = count;
            data = image.dataset;
            data.ref=count;
            document.getElementById('image'+count).appendChild(image); 
            jQuery(document.getElementById('image'+count)).removeClass('disable');
            jQuery(document.getElementById('img'+count)).addClass('action editable img ');
        };
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
```

Waiting for any better answer..